# Tablesorter ajax name in url

Tags: jquery, ajax

Данные для вывода в таблицу беру с помощью `ajax` запроса. При этом отправляется http запрос вида: `...&filter[0]=342&...`

В запросе указано, что я делаю фильтрацию первого (`index=0`) по значению `342`. На сервере можно сделать условие при обработке `http` параметров, что `0` индекс соответствует такому-то полю в БД. Но данный факт не даст мне написать универсальный метод для обработки `ajax` запроса из любой таблицы.

Вопрос:

1. Как сделать так, что бы вместо `filter[0]=342`, смог отправить `filter[unixtime]=342`. Принимая, что я, на пример, укажу в `th` фильтруемого столбца укажу `name="unixtime"`.
2. Можно вместо индексов использовать имена столбцов?

Comment: фильтрация или сортировка? при чем тут tablesorter?

Comment: @Jean-Claude
Ну вообще и то и то.
test.pl?page=0&size=50&filter[3]=23&col[4]=0. При чем тут tablesorter? - использую данный плагин для JQuery
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
          url = url.replace("[3]", "[unixtime3]");
          url = url.replace("[4]", "[unixtime4]");
          $("#myTable").trigger('changingUrl', url);
          return url;
      },
```

В этом случае получаю то что мне и необходимо